# wordpress custom menu class name

Tags: php, wordpress

I wanted to add some class name of my wordpress custom menu that I created

`<?php 
                    wp_nav_menu( array(
                        'theme_location'  => 'social-menu'
                    )); 
                ?>`

`function register_main_menus() {`
        `register_nav_menus(array(`
            `'social-menu' => __('Social Menu', 'sm')`
));`<br>`
}`

```
`add_action('init', 'register_main_menus');`
```

to something like this.. I can see the option to add title attributes in admin panel but not class. How can I achieve to get those class name in each of them?

`<ul>`
`<li><a href="#" class="social-youtube-icon"></a></li>`
`<li><a href="#" class="social-wordpress-icon"></a></li>`
`<li><a href="#" class="social-facebook-icon"></a></li>`
`</ul>`

Answer (score 2):

just got this one working!

```
    function add_menuclass($ulclass) {
        return preg_replace('/<a title="social-youtube-icon"/', '<a title="social-youtube-icon" class="social-youtube-icon"', $ulclass, 1);
    }
    add_filter('wp_nav_menu','add_menuclass');
```